# The darker shade on app screen?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to get a darker tone to my app screens and I want to set a user instructions icons on the front. Like here:

[image]

I am not getting the same effect. I have tried like for two hours. I have changed the opacity and transparency. Could some expert guide me on how to get the same effect as the above image? The image that I have worked on is this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just add black layer and make its opacity 75%**
then put all your object below your black layer and it should work perfectly

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put a black rectangle on top and from the **Transparency panel** set the blend opacity to **Multiply**, Opacity = 70%.

Add the explanation text on a top layer.

[image]